# Trigger vs procedure to set status inactive automatically when expire_date is less than now

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

In my schema I have columns:
status
start_date
end_date

I want to implement a procedure which keeps running in background and whenever the end_date has been reached it should set status to inactive.

How can this be achieved using procedures.

Note: I use Postgres.

Comment: Is this the only thing that affects status? If so, why *store* it at all? Even if not, treating anything having an end_date in the past *as if* the status is invalid, during `select` is still, to my mind, cleaner than trying to automatically change data when no query is actually interacting with the DB.

Comment: You might consider creating a VIEW that shows the status. As pointed out above, there's no need to create a trigger for such simple task.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever force change of status to active or inactive is also possible by user from UI.
We do filter out rows which have status as inactive and also end_date already over during cleaner.
But in UI user expects the status to autochange to inactive when end_date is passed.

Comment: @AlexM how can view be helpful?
I need to set the status and not check.

Comment: @Ashi the question is why do you need to physically store the status at all if it can be easily calculated at run-time? That's what VIEWs are for. But if you insist on saving the status, then you need to create a cron-job that will check the records and update them accordingly. And it is not a perfect approach. So I would recommend you to stick with the first option.